# TimeoutException after an element was cliked with true ExpectedConditions

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I get error on the last line of the code

```
wd.get("https://www.thehost.com/profile.php");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(wd, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("input[value='a_working_locator']"))); //line 224
wd.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value='a_working_locator']")).click(); //line 225
```

error

> org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timeout loading page after
>   5000ms Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver Session
>   ID: 78736d2b-3c64-4bec-a205-2ceb16ad8680  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>   ...
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:83)
>     at main.FirefoxHeadlessServer.run(FirefoxHeadlessServer.java:225)   at
>   main.FirefoxHeadlessServer.main(FirefoxHeadlessServer.java:154)

How cat it be if ExpectedConditions was true on line 224 and then on line 225 I get error?

Comment: Try with elementToBeClickable...

Comment: @Grasshopper I'v already tried it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are trying to invoke `click()` on the same element after invoking *WebDriverWait* instead of the clause `visibilityOfElementLocated` use the clause [`elementToBeClickable`](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#elementToBeClickable-org.openqa.selenium.By-) as follows :

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input[value='a_working_locator']"))).click();
```